# No labels in sjplot tab_df

Tags: r, label, sjplot

I am trying to build a table with sjplot and the tab_df function but fail to get the label names in the table:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(stargazer)


Region<-c("Berlin", "Hamburg", "Berchtesgarden")
Sensor<-c("Riegl ", "Riegl ", "Riegl ")
Platform<-c("Aircraft", "UAV", "Helicoper")
Acquisition_Year <-c("2002", "2002", "2002")
Month<-c("August", "September", "July")
Flight_Height<-c("400-600m AGL","400-600m AGL","400-600m AGL")

LidarAcq<-as.data.frame(cbind(Region, Sensor, Platform, Acquisition_Year, Month, Flight_Height))
LidarAcq

attr(LidarAcq$Region, "label") <- "Region"
attr(LidarAcq$Sensor, "label") <- "Sensor"
attr(LidarAcq$Platform, "label") <- "Platform"
attr(LidarAcq$Acquisition_Year, "label") <- "Acquisition Year"
attr(LidarAcq$Month, "label") <- "Month"
attr(LidarAcq$Flight_Height, "label") <- "Flight Height"


tab_df(LidarAcq, title = "Lidar Acquisition Parameters" , file= "~/LidarAcq.doc")
```

As I understand, sjplot is supposed to automatically recognise the labels...

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also cannot get sjplot to recognize the label for each column. You can use col.header and a character vector ("labels") to name your columns instead.

```
labels <- c("Region", "Sensor", "Platform", "Acquisition Value", "Month", "Flight Height")

tab_df(LidarAcq, 
title = "Lidar Acquisition Parameters" ,
col.header = labels,
file= "~/LidarAcq.doc")
```